# Rendering Offscreen in React Native

Tags: react-native, internals

Is there an API for offscreen rendering in React Native? I've not seen anything in the official documentation that seems to allow rendering an arbitrary view stack offscreen. I've come across stuff like [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot), as well as a few internal pieces like [Renderer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-prod.js) in concert with `UIManager.takeSnapshot`, but it's not obvious how to make those pieces work. I've looked into creating a separate `RCTSurface` as well in a custom Native Module, but that seems to cause a deadlock when creating a `RCTSurface` for a `RCTBridge` that already has a `RCTRootView` defined.

Is there an easy way to simply render some arbitrary view stack in React Native offscreen? Is there some internal API that can be used for this?

Comment: If I understand what you want, `RCTSurface` is what you need. Simply create an instance of RCTSurface, call `start`, enforce size (call `setMinimumSize:maximumSize:`, wait for some finishing event, get `.view`, set size for this view, capture the content of the view using standard UIKit APIs.